# how to improve feature selection for Naive bayes?

Tags: java, machine-learning

I am working on some thousand of documents needed to be classified into some 5 categories. I am using Naive Bayes classifier for it. When I tested it on some few sample mails it was working fine but when I actually apply it to original dataset the calculations are getting really complexed as there are more number of features. At one point the values are so small that they are almost zero. So my question is how to avoid this problem of getting very small values and how to improve feature selection?

Comment: That's the hardest bit. There is a special branch in ML devoted just for feature selection. Except for relying on features that proved to score well for text classification cannot really see a better way than selecting a feature and scoring it on your test set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka supports feature selection by searching through all possible combination of features in the data to find the subset that works best (based on score and ranking) for prediction. Check the [example code](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/weka-attribute-selection) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

We also observed that Naive Bayes tends to give poor probability estimates when using a large number of features. So feature selection is indeed a good idea here. In additon, it is always a good idea to look into feature selection especially if your feature set is extremly large. If it is done right it can improve the generalization ability of your learning model.

There various ways to perform feature selection for Naive Bayes:

- The first step is usually to use to calculate the Information Gain or the Gain Ratio (see Weka) for each feature and rank them by these values. This first ranking evaluation helps to identify the most relevant features and those that can be deleted. The advantage of this method is, that it works very fast even on large datasets. On the other hand, it does not consider the fact that features might be correlated.
- Try Weka's Cfs Evaluation (works fairly well with BestFirst-Search). It calculates the worth of a subset by the correlation of features with the class variable (related to Information Gain) and by the inter-feature correlation. Since you need to search for the best feature set, this method is far more expensive. However, it can help to reduce the number of features dramatically. For us it helped to reduce the number of features from 30,000 to ~50.
- Another approach is using PCA (principal component analysis). When using the resulting prinical component vectors as features, it is possible to select only those that explain the major variance in the dataset. With this method you actually still have to inject all features to your method but Naive Bayes has less feature to deal with and, consequently, gives better probability estimates.

Obviously, there are more ways to perform feature selection such as using the Naive Bayes classifier to evaluate different feature sets. However, in the context of large scale datasets, we found such methods far too slow.

All the above methods are available in the Weka ML library. Please make also sure that when you select features, you do that only by considering your training data. You should never use part of the testing data for feature selection.

Answer (score 2):

Feature selection just to avoid values close to zero is unnecessary---if your Naive Bayes classifier works in log space, then \prod_i p(f_i | c_j) becomes \sum_i log p(f_i | c_j), which won't underflow. You can compute the posterior probabilities by:

p(c_j | f) = exp([ log p(c_j) + log p(f|c_j) ] - sum_j' [ log p(c_j') + log p(f|c_j') ])

As to whether feature selection is necessary for other reasons... it can be, depending on the problem. Dimensionality reduction is often better for document classification, as it can uncover similar/synonymous words. But ultimately you'll have to implement them to see---try LSA/PCA first, as they're simplest. Or ditch Naive Bayes and go straight for a multi-layer neural net if you have enough data (you'll get non-linearities and reduced dimensionality that directly helps with the classification task).